# NoSuchMethodError using OWL API 4.0.x

Tags: java, guava, guice, owl-api

I downloaded OWL API (4.0.1 and 4.0.2). But it needed plenty of dependencies that are nowhere mentioned. I downloaded dependency JARs from maven pom.xml file (found it somewhere for version OWL API 4.0.1). List of jars:

[image: JARS]

First of all, it was error with RDFFormat (need to add sesame lib, which was not in pom.xml.
But I still have "**NoSuchMethodError**" errors. 
First one was

```
com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull
```

(with Guava 17.0).I updated it to 18.0, now its

```
com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime
```

Here on stackoverflow is answer for this:

> You most likely have both a recent version of Guava and either
>   google-collect or a version of Guava prior to 3.0 on your classpath

But no, I dont have old Guava lib named google-collect(ions).

Comment: Are you actually using Maven?

Comment: No, I don't.  I wasn't able to find dependencies so I create maven project and download JARs from pom.xml and copy to my project (JavaFX).

Comment: The direct dependencies are here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.owlapi%7Cowlapi-distribution%7C4.0.2%7Cbundle
If you're after the indirect dependencies in an easy format, download owlapi-osgidistribution and open the jar. The lib folder contains the required dependencies. But I'd recommend using a build tool that can manage dependencies for you, like maven or gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you responses. I use

```
-verbose:class
```

and found out, that package for that class is from

```
gephi-toolkit.jar
```

Tt has google-collection too ... so yeah, different versions.

Answer (score 3):

Maven dependencies are transitive. If you don't want to use Maven for some reason you'll need to include all of them. Here's the dependency tree for owlapi 4.0.2.

```
[INFO] \- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-distribution:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-model:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-util:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-api:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-languages:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-datatypes:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-binary:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-n3:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-nquads:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-ntriples:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-rdfjson:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-rdfxml:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-trix:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-turtle:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-rio-trig:jar:2.7.12:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java-sesame:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO]    |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.semarglproject:semargl-sesame:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.semarglproject:semargl-core:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.semarglproject:semargl-rdfa:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.semarglproject:semargl-rdf:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0-beta:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:jar:4.0-beta:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    \- net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:jar:3.0.3:compile
```

For the most part, your life will be much easier using Maven (or some other modern build tool). It deals with dependency issues like this so you don't have to. If you're stuck with ant for some reason you could also take a look at [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).