# OWL API NoSuchMethodError in saveOntology() call

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, owl, owl-api

I am trying to call an OWL API java program through terminal and it crashes, while the exact same code is running ok when I run it in IntelliJ.

The exception that rises in my main code is this:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.RDFResource.idRequiredForIndividualOrAxiom()'
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.renderer.RDFXMLRenderer.render(RDFXMLRenderer.java:204)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.render(RDFRendererBase.java:448)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderOntologyHeader(RDFRendererBase.java:441)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.render(RDFRendererBase.java:247)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.renderer.RDFXMLStorer.storeOntology(RDFXMLStorer.java:51)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.storeOntology(AbstractOWLStorer.java:142)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.storeOntology(AbstractOWLStorer.java:106)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.saveOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1347)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.saveOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
        at com.stelios.JavaExplanations.main(JavaExplanations.java:112)
```

It seems as if calling `idRequiredForIndividualOrAxiom()` on an `RDFResource` object doesn't find the method that is inherited by `RDFNode` class, but I have no clue why.

In order to post here, I kept only the `saveOntology` call in a minimal example and the exception that is thrown is the same with extra steps:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.RDFResource.idRequiredForIndividualOrAxiom()'
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.renderer.RDFXMLRenderer.render(RDFXMLRenderer.java:204)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.renderer.RDFXMLRenderer.render(RDFXMLRenderer.java:249)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderEntity(RDFRendererBase.java:298)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.render(RDFRendererBase.java:292)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.lambda$renderEntities$6(RDFRendererBase.java:285)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1033)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderEntities(RDFRendererBase.java:285)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderInOntologySignatureEntities(RDFRendererBase.java:269)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.renderOntologyComponents(RDFRendererBase.java:253)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.RDFRendererBase.render(RDFRendererBase.java:248)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.renderer.RDFXMLStorer.storeOntology(RDFXMLStorer.java:51)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.storeOntology(AbstractOWLStorer.java:142)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractOWLStorer.storeOntology(AbstractOWLStorer.java:106)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.saveOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1347)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.saveOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1333)
        at com.stelios.JavaExplanations.main(JavaExplanations.java:47)
```

In both my original code and the minimal example I call java with: `java -cp /home/stelios/java_explanations/target/java_explanations-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.stelios.JavaExplanations`

Here is the minimal example that repeats this behavior for me. This is the Java code:

```java
package com.stelios;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.*;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;

public class JavaExplanations {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, FileNotFoundException, OWLOntologyStorageException {
        String ontology1 = "/home/stelios/Desktop/huiyfgds/ONTO_ASRTD_hz162pai";
        String ontology2 = "/home/stelios/Desktop/huiyfgds/ONTO_INFRD_hz162pai";

        OWLOntologyManager ontology_manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology asserted_ontology = ontology_manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(ontology1));
        ontology_manager.saveOntology(asserted_ontology, new StreamDocumentTarget(new FileOutputStream(ontology2)));
    }
}
```

This is the `pom.xml` in IntelliJ:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stelios.expl</groupId>
    <artifactId>java_explanations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlexplanation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlexplanation</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.semanticweb.hermit</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.519</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

I think that most probably it is some dependency/version error but I don't see how this can be. I package everything I need in the jar file I give as classpath, defining the wanted versions in pom.xml, and in this jar I can find only one org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/RDFResource.class file.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55629878/owl-api-nosuchmethoderror) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766193/nosuchmethoderror-using-owl-api-4-0-x) I thought about having 2 different versions of OWL API, as I had another .jar with OWL API version 3.4.9 in it, in the directory tree. I moved the file and rebuilt the maven package just to be sure, and (as expected) no change.

Other than the saveOntology() call, my original program is working as intended.

The only thing out of the ordinary is that IntelliJ is giving me a `Plugin 'maven-assembly-plugin:' not found` problem, which I haven't managed to solve in any way, and have been ignoring as it hasn't been an issue in any of the operations I have needed. (If you know how to solve it of course, give me suggestions, but my main problem is the earlier mentioned exception).

**EDIT** Here is the `mvn dependency:tree` output.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.stelios.expl:java_explanations >-----------------
[INFO] Building java_explanations 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ java_explanations ---
[INFO] com.stelios.expl:java_explanations:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlexplanation:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-api:jar:5.1.19:compile (version selected from constraint [5.0.0,5.9.9])
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-tools:jar:5.1.19:compile (version selected from constraint [5.0.0,5.9.9])
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.owlapi:telemetry:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-parsers:jar:5.1.19:compile (version selected from constraint [5.0.0,5.9.9])
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-distribution:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-compatibility:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-apibinding:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-impl:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-oboformat:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.sourceforge.owlapi:owlapi-rio:jar:5.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-rdf-api:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-model:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-languages:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-datatypes:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-binary:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-n3:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-nquads:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-ntriples:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-rdfjson:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-jsonld:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-rdfxml:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-trix:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-turtle:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-rio-trig:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-util:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:jar:0.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-osgi:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-osgi:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.vsonnier:hppcrt:jar:0.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:22.0:compile (version selected from constraint [18.0,22.0])
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile (version selected from constraint [2.0.0,4))
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.owlapi:org.semanticweb.hermit:jar:1.4.5.519:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-c14n:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:compile
[INFO] |  +- gnu.getopt:java-getopt:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |        \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:jar:0.11.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.25:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.339 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-27T13:06:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: you definitely have a version conflict. Check the dependencies with `mvn dependeny:tree`

Comment: `mvn dependeny:tree` threw a `NoPluginFoundForPrefixException`, so I revisited IntelliJ's `Plugin 'maven-assembly-plugin:' not found` thing. I solved this problem by adding the plugin as a dep. (shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/dependency-info.html)), but the `tree` command still crashed & my issue remained. I (randomly) added `<version>3.3.0</version>` in the `<plugin></plugin>` scope for `maven-assembly-plugin` and this somehow solved my original problem! `tree` command still fails. Any insight on all these? It got solved randomly without learning anything.

Comment: it was a typo from my side ... `mvn dependency:tree` would print the tree

Comment: Damn I am blind haha. I added the output in my post.

Comment: `tree` output is the same regardless of existence of `<version>3.3.0</version>` in my `pom.xml` that it seems that solves it.

Comment: as I said, you have conflicting versions: you have `5.1.9` and `5.1.19` mixed. The method was rename in [this commit](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/commit/10ec8f30f0442b2ee7e64f93979e1d1496c9de93#diff-1a26230aee05ad8598b270fc9ab78c802737aff1f11f4a459fee4789cd213290), i.e. before `5.1.19` - you should change your dependency `owlapi-distribution` to `5.1.19`

Comment: Yes, that is clear, thank you. But why did `maven-assembly-plugin` version declaration in `pom.xml` affected whether or not the Exception would be thrown?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, the root problem was the conflict between 5.1.19 (transitive from owlexplanation 5.0.0) and 5.1.9 in the pom. Regarding the assembly plugin, as the issue here is class files with the same name in different jar files, assembling all class files in one jar would overwrite one version with another - and if things happen in a certain order you end up accidentally solving the conflict by having overwritten one version with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments of the post, my problem is fixed, so I thought I'd collect a closing answer here to not leave the post pending.

**The actual solution**: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854565/owl-api-nosuchmethoderror-in-saveontology-call?noredirect=1#comment125301059_70854565) nicely by [@UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser), the issue was that I had conflicting maven package versions in my dependencies. Bringing everything in sync with each other solved the issue.

**Incidental solution**: As I wrote in the comments [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854565/owl-api-nosuchmethoderror-in-saveontology-call?noredirect=1#comment125300235_70854565), specifically defining `<version>3.3.0</version>` for the `maven-assembly-plugin` happened to solve the issue. But this was only chance, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854565/owl-api-nosuchmethoderror-in-saveontology-call?noredirect=1#comment125372143_70854565) by [@Ignazio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197045/ignazio), just because the order of "assembling" things changed, overwriting the conflicting package.

Huge thanks to both for the help.